# PowerShell Preemptive Authentication

Tags: rest, powershell

I am kind of stuck here, I am trying to make an http call with credentials and client token from PowerShell uing "GET" to an in-house web application (I did not create). I keep getting error 500 from the server.

This application requires Preemptive authentication. The first time I got this to work was in ReadyAPI when I selected the "Authenticate Pre-emptively" radio, the request worked.

This is the definition according to ReadyAPI that the radio button does

> Pre-emptive auth – Specifies if ReadyAPI will wait until an authorization challenge is received to send the credentials. The parameter has the following options:
>
> Use global preference – Use the settings defined in the HTTP Settings global preferences.
>
> **Authenticate pre-emptively – For this request only. Do not wait until an authorization challenge is received to send the credentials.**

I have seen that in C# there is a preemptive auth setting however I haven't found any such equivalent for PowerShell.

Has anyone ever run into this issue before? Is there a way powershell can issue a pre-emptive authentication?

This is what I have, but this is just basic setup...

```
$base64AuthInfo = 
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 
$user, $pass)))
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String], String]]"
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add('X-IBM-Client-ID', $clientId )

$uri = "https://myURI/development/authorization/token"

$invoke = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Method Post -Uri $uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Through shear luck... this fixed the pre-emptive authentication

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```